# MIPS Saving to a register where the address is a variable

Tags: mips, cpu-registers

So I'm doing homework and a problem is asking me to save an instruction to a register. this is the problem.

Assume that the values of a, b, i, and j are in registers $s0, $s1, $t0, and $t1, respectively. Also, assume that register $s2 holds the base address of the array D.

```
for(i=0; i<a; i++) 
for(j=0; j<b; j++)
D[4*j] = i + j;
```

having to write this in MIPS, and i have almost 90% of it, what im having problems with, is saving the results of i+j to D[4*j]. this is the code i have inside of the nested loop.

```
add $t2, $t0, $t1 # add i to j and store to temp
sll $t3, $t1, 4 # offset of j*4
add $t3, $s2, $t3 #add offset with base of D
```

normally, the other problems give me the value of the address, like B[8], so i would just use the constant 32. but with saving using a variable, im not sure how to do this, as it requires a constant.
Im almost certain that `sw $t2, 0($t3)($s2)` would not work. Am i just missing the obvious?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to increment your address by 4*4 (if `D` is an array of `int`s).

This correspond to this C code :

```
for(int i=0; i<a; i++)
    for(int j=0, int *pd=&D[0]; j<b; j++,pd+=4)
        *pd=i+j;
```

And a mips implementation can be with your hypothesis

> Assume that the values of a, b, i, and j are in registers $s0, $s1, $t0, and $t1, respectively. Also, assume that register $s2 holds the base address of the array D.

```
      add  $t0,$r0,$r0   #j=0
loopi:
       addi $t1,$r0,$r0   #j=0
       mov  $t3,$s2       #$t3=@D
loopj:
       add  $t2, $t0, $t1#add i to j and store to temp
       sw   $t2, 0($t3)  #store result in *t3
       addi $t3, 16      #t3+=4
       addi $t1, 1       #j++
       blt  $t1,$s1,loopj#j<b?
       addi $t0,1        #i++
       blt  $t0,$s0,loopi#i<a?
```

BTW, the `j` loop writes over previous `D` values for successive `ì` and only the last value will remain in `D`. Maybe your code is wrong. Or it can be replaced by

```
for(int j=0; j<b; j++)
        D[4*j]=a-1+j;
```